# pattern matching while using ls command in bash script

Tags: regex, sh, ls

In a sh script, I am trying to loop over all files that match the following pattern
`abc.123` basically abc. followed by only numbers, number following `.` can be of any length.
Using

`$ shopt -s extglob`
`$ ls abc.+([0-9])`

does the job but on terminal and not through the script. How can I get only files that match the pattern?

Comment: Are you sure the script is being run with `bash`, and not `sh`?

Comment: thanks for that. it's a sh script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `sh` and not `bash`, and presumably you also want to be POSIX compliant, you can use:

```
for f in ./*
do
    echo "$f" | grep -Eq '^\./abc.[0-9]+$' && continue
    echo "Something with $f here"
done
```

It will work fine with filenames with spaces, quotes and such, but may match some filenames with line feeds in them that it shouldn't.

If you tagged your question `bash` because you're using bash, then just use extglob like you described.

Answer (score 2):

if I understood you right, the pattern could be translated into regex:

```
^abc\.[0-9]+$
```

so you could

keep using `ls` and grep the output. for example:

```
ls *.*|xargs -n1|grep -E '^abc\.[0-9]+$'
```

or use `find`

find has an option `-regex`